# Existence of a generator over multiplication for integers modulo p

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

If we consider the integers modulo a prime $p$, then for every $x \not \equiv 0$ (mod $p$), we can get any $b \not \equiv 0$ by adding $x$ a number of times to itself.

*Is the same true for multiplication? That is, is there a number $x$ which, multiplied the right number of times to itself will give any other number modulo $p$?*

I have done some research and it seams that, if this is true, it makes modular integers a cyclic group over multiplication. From what I found, it might be related to Lagrange's theorem. However, I would be interested in a lower level answer, if one exists. I also believe Fermat's little theorem would follow from this (though there are more straightforward ways to get there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This write-up](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf) by Keith Conrad contains seven proofs of this result. More generally, any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Now eight proofs.

Comment: Now nine, @KCd ;-)